# How to check which domains and groups I belong to?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, windows-7, command-line-interface

This is pertaining to Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2, but probably may apply to other versions.

**Question 1**: How to find out preferably from CLI all the domains a user belongs to (it is probably not trivial, but somehow it can be done)?

**Question 2**: How to find out all the groups a user is a member of form a domain that this user is not currently logged to (provided a user knows the required credentials)?

Comment: An AD  user account may only exist in and belong to a single AD domain.

Comment: Out of curiosity - up to how many domains do you expect a user to belong to in your setup?

Comment: 5 different domains. Or rather 5 different accounts in 5 domains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @joeqwerty pointed out, a user may only reside in a single domain.  What you're likely interested to know is how trusts are configured between the various domains/forests. The cmdline tool I use for this is `nltest`

Due to group nesting, there isn't an elegant way to get group membership of a user across all domains/forests. The best way would be to enumerate all groups within each domain and check membership recursively for the desired user.

I don't have access to a domain joined system but the PowerShell code should look something like the following. Note that Get-ADGroup has max result limits which may need to be tweaked for your environment.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$AllDomainGroups = Get-ADGroup -Server DomainController -LdapFilter "(sAMAccountName=*)"
$AllDomainGroups | %{ [string[]]$MemberList = Get-ADGroupMember $_ -Recursive ; if($MemberList.Contains("SomeUser")){ Write-Host "$_`tTRUE" } else { Write-Host "$_`tFALSE" } }
```

Comment: I awarded the bounty to you because of nltest.

Answer (score 3):

The following code can lookup if a user has an account on another domain controller and then display all groups that that user belongs to. If you repeat this code for each domain it may get you what you need.

The credentials are those of a user who has permissions on the DC your looking at, server is the DC for the domain you want to check. Name would need to be the name of a user (Fist and last) exactly how it appears on the accounts.

You could modify this to take input or loop through a set of domains (If you have forest trusts)

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

#Set Name
$Name = "Nick Young"

# Create Password
$password = "password" | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force

# Set Username
$username = "domain\username"

# Create Credential
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username,$password)

$Server = "server.fqdn.com"

$Domain1Account = @(Get-ADUser -Server $Server -Credential $credential -Filter {Name -eq $Name})

# SHow Message
Write-Host "Domain 1 Account" -forgroundcolor Yellow

# Display Info
if( $Domain1Account.count -lt 1 )
{
   echo "No Account"
}
else
{
   $Domain1Account | FT Name,UserPrincipalName
   $Domain1Account | Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Server $Server | FT Name,distinguishedName
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732952.aspx DSQuery. If I get right your question this one here should help.

Answer (score 0):

Oh my god, all the scripts above. What's wrong with **"whoami /all**"? Give you all info you asked, except that pointed out already by someone above, a user belongs to only one domain.

Comment: whoami doesn't account for nesting groups

Comment: @user2320464: to be fair, few tool give you nested groups, and most of the time, direct membership is good enough. On the other hand, get-adgroupmember doesn't work quite well retrieving/resolving foreign domain memberships. If I have to pick one over the other, whoami gets my vote all the time.